# How do I copy data from one array to another?

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to move the data from `CF` array to `d` array, however I have not been successful. When I ReDim Preserve the `d` array after the For Next I am still not successful.

What is the issue here?

```
Function DPB(rate As Double, ByRef CF As Variant) As Variant

Dim d() As Variant
For k = LBound(CF) To UBound(CF)  
   d(k) = CF(k) / (1 + rate) ^ (k - 1)  
Next k
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete code of the function and also add an example how you call the function.,

Answer (score 2):

since your' using 'Variant`s you can simply go:

```
Option Explicit
Function DPB(rate As Double, ByRef CF As Variant) As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    Dim d As Variant

    d = CF '< -- this will make a "Hard copy" of CF into d
    For k = LBound(d) To UBound(d)
        d(k) = CF(k) / (1 + rate) ^ (k - 1)
    Next

    DPB = d
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted I suggest to have a look at the following code

```
Option Explicit

Function DPB(rate As Double, ByRef CF As Variant) As Variant

    Dim k As Long
    Dim d() As Variant
    ReDim d(LBound(CF) To UBound(CF))

    For k = LBound(CF) To UBound(CF)

        d(k) = CF(k) / (1 + rate) ^ (k - 1)

    Next k
    DPB = d
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim v(0 To 1) As Variant

    v(0) = 1
    v(1) = 2

    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = DPB(2, v)

End Sub
```